# Как зациклить массив?

Tags: java, массивы

Допустим, дано 10 элементов в массиве. Мне нужно, чтобы при щелчке мыши в него сохранялись значения, а при заполнении первый элемент удалялся, на его место записывалось последнее значение, а затем этот элемент становился последним - как змея, кушающая свой хвост. Добавлять элементы могу `ArrayList (add значение)`, условие тоже простое `if (size > 10)`, но как сделать цикл? При том, что промежуточные значения должны сохраняться до тех пор, пока их не перезапишут. Не обязательно делать динамический массив, просто я к нему привык

Comment: Кольцевой буфер что ли?

Comment: Хм, не знаю, поищу. Пока такая идея (проверить до вечера не могу): 'if (size > 10) {[1] = [10]; for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) [i]++}' но как-то криво. P.s с мобильного код не могу оформить(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не обязательно делать это в условии. Если у вас `size = 10`, например, а при записи 11-го числа нужно перезаписать 1-й элемент в списке, используйте оператор деления по модулю `%`:

```
static int size = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(); // наш массив
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if (arr.size() < size) // если у нас первые элементы
            arr.add(i % size, i); // тогда записываем новые элементы
        else
            arr.set(i % size, i); // а тут уже ПЕРЕзаписываем новыми
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
        System.out.print(arr.get(j) + " ");
    }
}
```

---

**Вывод**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В примере записываем числа последовательно от 0 до 14 в `ArrayList`, где всего 10 элементов - в результате элементы со значениями 5-9 не перезаписались, а элементы 10-14 перезаписали стоящие там числа.